# Ubuntu Linux, Unable to set bitcoin datadir to a folder in different drive

Tags: bitcoin-core, ubuntu, datadir

I am trying to run a bitcoin node. I want to set the datadir to a folder located on drive other than on which I have installed ubuntu.
Folder I want to set as datadir:

```
/media/spider/Utils/bitcoin
```

with permissions

```
drwxrwxrwx 1 spider spider 448 اپریل   2 17:25 bitcoin
```

But when i try to run `bitcoin-core` i get this error

```
$  bitcoin bitcoin-core.daemon --datadir=/media/spider/Utils/bitcoin   
Error: Failed saving settings file:
- Error: Unable to open settings file /media/spider/Utils/bitcoin/settings.json.tmp for writing
```

Comment: Hi Asad Hayat, which version of Bitcoin Core are you running?

Comment: Bitcoin Core version v0.21.0 (Latest, Installed Yesterday via snap)

Comment: Try without snap once. Don't have enough reputation to comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applications in a Snap run in a container with limited access to the host system, you can install bitcoin-core with full filesystem access via the Luke-Jr repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:luke-jr/bitcoincore
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bitcoin
```

or download the release from here:
https://bitcoincore.org/bin/bitcoin-core-0.21.0/bitcoin-0.21.0-x86_64-linux-gnu.tar.gz
unpack and run bitcoind executable inside the bin folder.

Answer (score 1):

if installed via snap, try `snap connect bitcoin-core:removable-media`

more info [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1328448/official-bitcoin-client-fails-to-start-with-error-initializing-settings-failed)