# How do I configure BTCPayServer to use an alternative datadir and avoid 'Unable to open settings file' Error?

Tags: bitcoin-core, datadir, btcpay

Similar to:

[Ubuntu Linux, Unable to set bitcoin datadir to a folder in different drive](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/105089/ubuntu-linux-unable-to-set-bitcoin-datadir-to-a-folder-in-different-drive)

and

[I can't start bitcoind on Raspberry Pi. Why do I need settings.json.tmp when I didn't need it before?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/107115/i-cant-start-bitcoind-on-raspberry-pi-why-do-i-need-settings-json-tmp-when-i-d)

I am configuring BTCPayServer to use a datadir that is not my root directory because I don't have enough space on my root directory for my pruned BTCPayServer Node.
When configuring and running BTCPayServer I am logged in as root the entire time, root (obviously) has access to my alternative directory.
This can be verified by running `ls -l altdatadir`

It outputs (edited to be generic):

`drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Mar 28 16:23 altdatadir`

I applied the alternate paths to the appropriate lines in `docker-fragments/bitcoin.yml`.

When I run the setup script everything appears to start, however if I try to call bitcoin-cli.sh it tells me it is restarting along with its unique hash. When I run `docker logs (unique hash)` it outputs (edited to be generic):

```
Error: Settings file could not be written:
 - Error: Unable to open settings file /media/$USER/altdatadir/.bitcoin/settings.json.tmp for writing
```

I am assuming under the given setup core is already being run as root (because btcpay server is being run as root) , which is the only given solution to this issue when it has appeared in the 2nd similar question's situation. If it is not the case how do I force BTCPayServer-docker to run it as root?

If it is the case and I am root when running core, why do I not have the ability to write into the directory/files?